# Isomorphic representations have equal characters

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, characters

I have read the following sentence in Vinberg "linear representations of groups" pg.58:

"Since isomorphic representations are given in compatible basis by identical matrices, we see that isomorphic representations have equal characters "

But I do not understand the first half (the part before the comma) of the sentence, may be because I have not seen an example of it, could anyone give me an example please?

For the second half I understand it as the characters are the traces of the representations.

Comment: I think your question is "What does it mean for two representations to be isomorphic?" Is that right?

Comment: I want to see an example that shows equality of characters means isomorphic representations. @RghtHndSd

Comment: That is the converse of the statement you quoted.

Comment: Actually I want to know why those 2 statements are equivalent @RghtHndSd

Comment: What is the group in this context? Finite? Lie? Etc.

Comment: @RghtHndSd  yes it is the group $SU_{2}$